# One more heart that never beats

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking

It is from the Internet, I changed it a bit, I will put the link after it is  answered.

> I have a heart that never beats,
> I have a home but I never sleep.
> I can take a mans house and build anothers,
> And I love to play games with my many brothers.
> I am a king among my fools.
> I rhyme myself with my own home.
> Who am I?

Source:https://www.riddles.com/who-am-i-riddles

Comment: Anyone searching this riddle will find it easily on the internet, that is quite not a good one.

Comment: I just [pasted the whole riddle into Google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=I+have+a+heart+that+never+beats%2C+I+have+a+home+but+I+never+sleep.+I+can+take+a+mans+house+and+build+anothers%2C+And+I+love+to+play+games+with+my+many+brothers.+I+am+a+king+among+my+fools.+I+rhyme+myself+with+my+own+home.+Who+am+I%3F), and got https://www.braingle.com/brainteasers/3384/a-heart-that-never-beats.html

Comment: @math Will you post the link now the the riddle is answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you...

> The King of Hearts?

I have a heart that never beats,

> Heart, that's obvious.

I have a home but I never sleep.

> Is the 'deck of cards' its home?

I can take a mans house and build anothers,

> A King in a pack of playing cards can be part of a 'full house'. It can 'take' another's in that it can win a hand in a game of cards.

And I love to play games with my many brothers.

> You play games with cards. The 'brothers' are the other kings.

I am a king among my fools.

> Yes, a king. The fools are the jokers in the pack?

I rhyme myself with my own home.

> I'm guessing that 'King of Hearts' almost rhymes with 'deck of cards'?